# Incorrect value for column with Laravel 4

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a column created as follows in my Laravel 4 migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create(
        'templates',
        function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            // Omitted fields...
            $table->smallInteger('pages')->default(0);

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        }
    );
}
```

When I try to save the entity using

```
$entity->save();
```

in my controller, I get an error for that particular column when the field value is empty:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'pages' at row 1
```

I can fix this by creating a mutator in the model like so:

```
public function setPagesAttribute($value)
{
    if (empty($value)) {
        $this->attributes['pages'] = 0;
    }
}
```

But isn't Laravel / Eloquent supposed to be doing that in any case?

I'm just thinking, I'm doing something wrong here...

Comment: I assume you could add ->nullable() in your Schema and try?

Comment: @petkostas "nullable" shouldn't be used here since he wants the value to default to 0. A nullable column is only used when it makes sense for a column to have no value, but 0 is more appropriate for a numerical field, so that he doesn't need to check for NULL inside of his code when using the value (depending on what he wants the code to do; null may be appropriate).

Comment: I'm only getting this on my Mac, when we deploy our code, it doesn't happen on our Ubuntu test machine. It appears to be a MySQL configuration issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered a solution online: http://www.garethalexander.co.uk/tech/mysql-5-incorrect-integer-value-column-id-row-1

Simply do the following:

- edit my.cnf
- comment out the line

  - sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
- And run $ mysql.server restart

Comment: You should probably fix the code too. Your "default" is not getting used at all, and you're technically passing a STRING (an empty one) into an integer column. You're turning off quite a bit of error-checking for your SQL tables that could cause unexpected behavior: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html

Comment: This happened to me while inserting NULL values with Laravel 4.2 - Fedora 21, here with MySQL 5.6. Thank you for posting! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an empty string is getting passed to the query for the Pages field (the default will only trigger if there's no value being passed for the field). I'm not sure how you're building your entity object, but you basically shouldn't be setting entity->pages at all when you want it to use the default value.

If you're getting pages via Input variables, using either Input::get('pages', 0) or Input::get('pages', null) should fix the problem.